# Which way do the white and green wires go in a usb connection?

Tags: usb

I am making a system that requires the white wires and the green wires (in usb cables) need to kind of be on a diode. Which one goes to the computer and which goes to the USB device?

Answer (score 3):

USB uses bidirectional differential signaling on the data lines - data is tranmitted both ways (one way at a time) over the pair of data wires.

USB is a very complex communication system, and shouldn't be messed with, unless you really understand the system.